# multiple condition at select-object expression powershell

Tags: powershell

I am getting IP and Name data from infoblox API like below

[image: my_redacted_screenshot]

As you can see there are certain entries which are **blank** or having like **"gateway"/"reserved s"**

I need to eliminate such entries and write rest of the data in csv. currently I am writing all of the data using below code

```
$url = "https://this.infoblox.fqdn.local/wapi/v2.10.5/ipv4address?network=$subnet&status=USED&_return_as_object=1"
    

$lapw = Get-Content "E:\EncryptedPassword\pw.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content E:\EncryptedPassword\aes.key)
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("USER",$lapw)
$Result_IPAddress = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Credential $creds -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json'


$Result_IPAddress.Result |
Select-Object @{Name='IPAddress';Expression='IP_Address'},                
              @{Name='IPName';Expression={$_.names -join ' ;'}}  | Export-Csv -Path "E:\Used_IP_Details.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
```

Please let me know how can I filter the data. as of now I got only these 3 types which I have to ignore writing but later there might be more such keywords which I have to ignore and filter out the data.

I tried giving like this

```
@{Name='IPName';Expression={$_.names -join ' ;'} -and {$_.names -match 'reserved s'} -or {$_.names -match 'gateway'}}
```

but problem is I am not getting how to give condition for **Blank** and there are certain entries which starts with **"reserved"** but have followed hostname in it so I have to keep them. So have to have strict matching.

---

With respect to @MathiasR.Jessen answer, tried below

```
$addressesAndNames = $Result_IPAddress.Result |
Select-Object @{Name='IPAddress';Expression='IP_Address'},                
              @{Name='IPName';Expression={$_.names -join ' ;'}}  

$addressesAndNames | Where-Object $_.IPName -notlike 'reserved *' | Where-Object $_.IPName -notlike 'gateway' | Where-Object $_.IPName -ne '' | Export-Csv -Path "E:\ComparisonFiles\InfoBlox_Used_IP_Details.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
```

but getting error like

```
Where-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again.
At E:\InfoBlox_CMDB_Comparison_Report.ps1:101 char:35
+ $addressesAndNames | Where-Object $_.IPName -notlike 'reserved *' | W ...
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

Comment: Filter the object with `Where-Object` and pipe the result to `Select-Object`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select-Object` is not for filtering. For that, you'll want to use `Where-Object`:

```
$addressesAndNames = $Result_IPAddress.Result | Select-Object @{Name='IPAddress';Expression='IP_Address'},@{Name='IPName';Expression={$_.names -join ' ;'}}

# use `Where-Object` to filter the output from `Select-Object`
$addressesAndNames |Where-Object IPName -notlike 'reserved *' |Export-Csv ...
```

You can chain as many excluding `Where-Object` commands as you like:

```
$addressesAndNames |Where-Object IPName -notlike 'reserved *' |Where-Object IPName -notlike '*gateway*' |Export-Csv ...
```